# Reactor 2.0 EventBus - how to aggregate and pause to handle replies

Tags: java, multithreading, reactor, project-reactor

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this use case in Reactor (2.X) using the EventBus

Main thread dispatches an event to topic "foo" using a threadPoolExecutor. The event may go to some number of consumers that have subscribed to "foo". These consumers inspect the event data and decide if there is a problem or not.

I want main thread to pause and wait until one of the conditions are met:

1. All consumers get the event, finish running and find no problems. Main thread resumes execution
2. One of the consumers finds a problem, Main thread should throw an exception
3. One of the consumers takes too long to run, Main thread should resume execution but log a warning

So something like

```
// dispatch event to all consumers
notify("foo", event);
// wait on all consumers to either finish or timeout after 100 ms
// consumers are running on X separate threads, doing their analysis
boolean anyErrors = waitOnConsumers(100);
if(anyErrors){
    throw new BlockedExecutionException("A problem occurred");
}
```